# I want a Java Arabic stemmer

Tags: java, arabic, stemming, porter-stemmer

I'm looking for a Java stemmer for Arabic. 
I found a lib called "AraMorph" , but its output is uncontrollable and it makes formation to words which is unwanted.

Is there any other stemmer for Arabic ?

Answer (score 8):

Here is new Arabic stemmer: [Assem's Arabic light stemmer](http://www.arabicstemmer.com/) coded using Snowball framework and generated to many languages including Java.  You can use it by downloading libstemmer for Java [here](http://arabicstemmer.com/java/).

Answer (score 6):

You can find Kohja stemmer here:

http://zeus.cs.pacificu.edu/shereen/research.htm

Direct download:

http://zeus.cs.pacificu.edu/shereen/ArabicStemmerCode.zip

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @paradigmatic. I have asked my quesion because I did not know what stemming is. Following your answer I read about it a little bit.

Comment: I want API or Lib so that I can use in my project
Thanks any way :)

Comment: @Kareem: It is an API or lib... Check the second link I've posted.

Comment: The code is under the GPL license though. Quite restrictive for a stemming library. Can't be used in a commercial product. I can't even wrap it in a TokenFilter and contribute it to Lucene, since Apache License and GPL are incompatible.

Comment: It can be used in a web-based commercial product, SaaS for example, This way no redistributables are involved, so GPL has no problems with that!

Answer (score 3):

https://sourceforge.net/projects/arabicstemmer/

try this it is based on Shereen Khoja Algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

after digging I found the best solution is to implement my own stemmer using porter Algorithm so that I can tune my stemmer

Comment: What? It won't work! Arabic is typed in non-Latin letters and more importantly follows extremely different algorithmic approach than the other Latin languages. .... But I'm interested to know if it worked with you or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either Elkhoja stemmer or Lucene's [light stemmer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_3/api/contrib-analyzers/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ar/ArabicAnalyzer.html)